# Indicate the window is "always on top"

Tags: windows-10, automation, autohotkey

Good day!
I would like to add a red border/shadow to the window that is Always on top to identify its state. At the moment my way of identifying it is by reducing the opacity.
Any recommendation? Thanks

```
#SingleInstance, force

^f::
WinGetActiveTitle, Title
    WinGet, ExStyle, ExStyle, % Title
        if (ExStyle & 0x8){
            WinSet, AlwaysOnTop, Off, % Title
            WinSet, Transparent, 255, % Title
        } else {
            WinSet, AlwaysOnTop, On , % Title
            WinSet, Transparent, 230, % Title
        }
    Return
```

My Window version: Windows 10 Version 21H2

Comment: See AutoHotkey boards: https://www.autohotkey.com/boards/viewtopic.php?t=17535, https://www.autohotkey.com/boards/viewtopic.php?t=73197

Comment: Maybe another approach with less code? The first link is for an autohotkey gui and the second one needs a lot of libraries

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

```
#SingleInstance, force
^f::
SetTimer, CheckBorder, 500, -10
Id := WinActive("A"), t := 4 ; t = border thickness
WinGet, ExStyle, ExStyle, ahk_id %Id%
if (ExStyle & 0x8)
{
    WinSet, AlwaysOnTop, Off, ahk_id %Id%
    WinClose,% "ahk_id " Red%ID%
    WinIDs := StrReplace(WinIDs, "," ID), Red%ID% := ""
    Return
}
WinSet, AlwaysOnTop, On , ahk_id %Id%
MakeBorder:
WinGetpos, x, y, w, h, ahk_id %Id%
Gui, New, +ToolWindow -Caption +LastFound +AlwaysOnTop +E0x20 +HwndRed
Gui, Color, Red
WinSet, Region,% "0-0 "w "-0 "w "-"h " 0-"h " 0-0 "t "-"t " "w-t "-"t " "w-t "-"h-t " "t "-"h-t " "t "-"t
Gui, Show, x%x% y%y% w%w% h%h% NoActivate
Red%ID% := Red, Pos%ID% := x y w h, WinIDs .= "," ID
Return
CheckBorder:
DetectHiddenWindows, On
Loop, Parse, WinIDs, CSV
{
    IF !ID := A_LoopField
        Continue
    IF !WinExist("ahk_id " ID)
    {
        WinClose,% "ahk_id " Red%ID%
        WinIDs := StrReplace(WinIDs, "," ID), Red%ID% := ""
        Break
    }
    WinGetpos, x, y, w, h, ahk_id %ID%
    IF (x y w h) = Pos%ID%
        Continue
    WinClose,% "ahk_id " Red%ID%
    WinIDs := StrReplace(WinIDs, "," ID), Red%ID% := ""
    Goto, MakeBorder
}
Return
```